# Is there a tool to migrate Joomla/K2 entries into Craft?

Tags: craft-pro

I have a Joomla site with K2 installed, and a couple of thousands of articles (no custom fields) and corresponding images.

Is there a script to help migrate those into Craft? Or will I have to manually write something custom to move the content?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure there is anything specifically for importing from Joomla, but you could try the [Import](https://github.com/boboldehampsink/import) plugin. Depending on the data format, you may also be able to use the [Feed Me](https://github.com/engram-design/FeedMe) plugin.

Edit: Alternatively, a popular Craft CMS plugin maker (Barrel Strength Design) offers a commercial service to migrate/import data from Joomla -> Craft CMS. It's called [The Great Migration](http://thegreatmigration.net). (NOTE: I'm nothing to do with the service, I just had it bookmarked for future reference)