# Migrating Joomla K2 nested categories

Tags: categories, craft-pro

I have a large-ish site built with Joomla and K2, with articles stored in a hierarchy of categories..

What is the proposed way to recreate the Category hierarchy functionality?

What I am interested in is that when a user opens a parent category, he sees all items stored in this category, plus all items stored in children categories.
If he opens a child category, he sees items stored only in this category.

I have tried a demo installation, and experimented a bit with section types and categories, but what I need is some kind of parent-child relation in Categories or Sections.

Could you please help me clarify how these things are distinct and what would be best practice to achieve what I want?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: RitterKnight gives a [great answer](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/13828/45) for how you may choose to layout your categories in Craft. As for the migration itself, your options will be identical to those mentioned in [this thread...](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/13817/is-there-a-tool-to-migrate-joomla-k2-entries-into-craft)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Craft supports hierarchical, nested [categories](https://craftcms.com/docs/categories) out of the box.

It also supports hierarchical entries, assuming you used the [Structure](https://craftcms.com/features/section-types) section type (and not a channel or single).

Where Craft and Joomla differ is the *output on the front end* is completely up to you. There's no default "widget" or anything in Craft that is going to do exactly what you want.

Craft's [{% nav %}](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/nav) tag would help you output categories and sub categories. [This example](https://craftcms.com/support/structure-nav) uses a structure section but it's also applicable to nested categories as well.

There's a few recipes in the [Craft Cookbook](http://craftcookbook.net) that you might find helpful in this instance as well.